# Find pair by key within a vector of pairs

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I want to call the find function on a vector of pairs. At the time the find function is called I only have the key to search by.

My understanding is that I need to pass a function into find as an argument to do the comparison for me but I can't find a proper example.

The reason I'm sorting the pairs within a vector opposed to a map container is because I want to be able to **sort the pairs by value** after the population process.

```
    vector< pair<string, int> > sortList;
    vector< pair<string, int> >::iterator it;

    for(int i=0; i < Users.size(); i++)
    {
        it = find( sortList.begin(), sortList.end(), findVal(Users.userName) );

        //Item exists in map
        if( it != sortList.end())
        {
            //increment key in map
            it->second++;
        }
        //Item does not exist
        else
        {
            //Not found, insert in map
            sortList.push_back( pair<string,int>(Users.userName, 1) );
        }
    }

    //Sort the list

    //Output
```

The implementation on `findVal` is the fuzzy area for me. I'd also be open to better ways of implementing the logic.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

you  don't need use `find`, please use `find_if`, this is the link:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/

```
auto it = std::find_if( sortList.begin(), sortList.end(),
    [&User](const std::pair<std::string, int>& element){ return element.first == User.name;} );
```

If you are using C++ standard before C++11, later, you'll need a function instead of a lambda:

```
bool isEqual(const std::pair<std::string, int>& element)
{
    return element.first ==  User.name;
}
it = std::find_if( sortList.begin(), sortList.end(), isEqual );
```

Comment: @DanielDC  Is your system setup for C++11?

Comment: Not sure, how can i check

Comment: Try `g++ --version` or `clang++ --version` or `compilerExeName --version`

Comment: @DanielDC  But what compiler and version do you have?  If it is too old, the compiler will not have a chance of C++11 support.

Comment: Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
is that what your after ??

Comment: @DanielDC Yes, now I know that c++11 support is very possible.  Are you using Xcode or something else?

Comment: xCode is installed but i'm just doing it all from some text editor.

Comment: You probably need to compile with a flag like --std=c++11, or something similar. I don't know the equivalent flag for LLVM, but that works for GCC

Comment: @DanielDC  Okay, then I am assuming you are compiling from the command line.  When I invoke the command line via NetBeans on my MacBook Pro, the first part of it is `clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wall`

Comment: also can i pass User.name into this new function as a parameter??

Comment: @DanielDC I have been working up a lambda expression code sample showing how to sort a vector by the data element's data (e.g. name or integer value), but it looks like you already have your answer.  If you want to see how to use the lambda expression to make the `pair` go away, please ask.

Comment: how does the "bool isEqual" recieves the parameter: User.name; ?

Comment: First time, I get to know about find_if(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, UnaryPredicate pred).
I was trying to compare the struct which has two elements. find function did not work for that. Even did not work for pair<int, int>.

Comment: Why use a lambda instead of a function? To me it seems like a function would be much cleaner and easier to read

Answer (score 10):

From C++20, you can use [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/find) to write:

```
auto it = std::ranges::find(sortList, Users.userName, 
                            &std::pair<std::string, int>::first);
```

which is much easier to read. The 3rd argument is a projection, i.e. it says to look only at the `first` member of every `pair` in the vector, when comparing it against the second argument.