# How to search a vector of pairs by pair.first, and returning the entire pair?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of pairs, and I also have a number that is possibly equal to pair.first within the vector. I would like to search the vector using this number, and then if it is in the vector, return the entire pair. Here is code:

```
vector<pair<size_t, size_t>> = (psuedocode) {{0, 13}, {1, 12}, {3, 11}};
```

Now, I have a value called vertex, which may or may not be equal to one of the pair.first within the vector. I only have this information, which is enough for my purposes, to search the vector. If it is equal to one of the pair.first, I would like to return the entire pair. So basically I am searching within a vector of pair by pair.first, not by pair. How do I accomplish this?

Right now, I am using find method:

```
vector<pair<size_t, size_t>>::iterator it = find(v.begin(), v.end(), vertex);
```

Obviously, this does not work since vertex is of type "size_t", and is not a pair.

Comment: `std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), [vertex](auto const &p){return p.first == vertex;})`

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676301/find-pair-by-key-within-a-vector-of-pairs,  the answer users a function instead of a lambda. How does the function get the "vertex" parameter? Or in the context of that question, how does it get the "User" parameter?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The answer uses a lambda as well, and shows  how to capture the user parameter.

Comment: The answer uses a lambda in the first code segment, but a regular function in their second code segment. How does bool isEqual() get the User parameter, as from what I see only the parameter 'element' is passed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::find_if()` is better suited to the job in this case.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}};

  int vertex= 2;

  auto it = std::find_if(
      v.begin(), v.end(),
      [&vertex](std::pair<int, int> i) { return i.first == vertex; });

  std::cout << it->first << ", " << it->second << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2, 3
```